# Not getting correct output from coding question

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Have the function `QuestionsMarks(str)` take the str string parameter,
> which will contain single digit numbers, letters, and question marks,
> and check if there are exactly 3 question marks between every pair of
> two numbers that add up to 10. If so, then your program should return
> the string true, otherwise it should return the string false. If there
> aren't any two numbers that add up to 10 in the string, then your
> program should return false as well.
>
> For example: if str is `"arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"` then your program
> should return true because there are exactly 3 question marks between
> 6 and 4, and 3 question marks between 5 and 5 at the end of the
> string.

```
def QuestionsMarks(strParam):
  lists = []
  for index, character in enumerate(strParam):
      try:
          character = int(character)
      except Exception as e:
          None
      lists.append([index,character])

  numbers=[]
  for i in lists:
      if type(i[1])==int:
          numbers.append(i)

  true_counter = 0
  i = 0
  while i < len(numbers)-1:
      total = numbers[i][1] + numbers[i+1][1]
      if total == 10:
          tmp_list = lists[numbers[i][0]:numbers[i+1][0]]
          counter = 0
          for j in tmp_list:
              if j[1] == '?':
                  counter+=1
          if counter >= 3:
              true_counter+=1
      i+=1
    
  if true_counter >= 1:
    return "true"
  else:
    return "false"
  return strParam

print(QuestionsMarks("9???1???9??1???9"))
```

For input `"9???1???9??1???9"` the output was incorrect. The correct output is false.

I would like to know if there is an error in my code? Isn't the correct output true, which is the output I got?

Comment: `...?9??1?...` - the output should be `False`.

Comment: Yeah it has to be 3 between every pair, so your `true_counter` variable would have to equal the number of pairs that add up to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regural expression library (`re`, built-in into Python) will ease your work.

I have edited the function to support what you are presumably after:

```py
import re

def questionMarks(string:str):
    ret = "false"

    ls1 = [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x) for x in string.split("???")]
    if len(ls1) > 0:
        ret = "true"

    ls2 = []
    for item in ls1:
        if len(item) == 2:
            ls2.append(item[0])
            ls2.append(item[1])
        else:
            ls2.append(item)

    for i in range(0, len(ls2), 2):
        try:
            if int(ls2[i]) + int(ls2[i + 1]) != 10:
                ret = "false"
                break
        except IndexError:
            ret = "false"
            break

    return ret
```

Comment: The question says that all numbers that add up to 10 have to have 3 question marks between them, would this not return `True` if any numbers that add up to 10 have the question marks?

Comment: I think that's the problem with the ops answer too, it need to check that every pair that adds to 10 has 3 question marks between but his also returns `True` with any pair having matched

Comment: Please don't think I'm trying to put down your answer just trying to help it out. Your code is returning `'false'` for `'arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5'` but that should be `True`. Also, why did you change it to use strings instead of boolean values

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added handling for situations where two numerical values are in the same group. The reason for using strings instead of booleans is that the question explicitly states the desired return values are `"true"` and `"false"`, no other reason.

Comment: Good catch on the strings, I missed that!  When I run your code with `print(questionMarks("9???1???9??1???9"))` it prints `'true'` but that one is meant to be `'false'`

Comment: Yes, there was a small error in looping the second list, now fixed.

Comment: Nice, it gives correct for both now. One last thing, the question says that it has to be exactly three question marks. If you use `.split('???')` will it give false if there are, say, 4 question marks

Comment: ok i see the problem now! Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your answer is that it will return `True` if any pair that adds to 10 has `???` between them. However the question says that all pairs must have `???` between them not just one, so I came up with this:

```
import re

def QuestionMarks(string):
    string = re.sub(r"[^\d?]", "", string)

    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    question_counter = 0

    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit():
            if num1:
                num2 = num1
                num1 = int(char)

                if num1 + num2 == 10 and question_counter != 3:
                    return 'false'

            else:
                num1 = int(char)

            question_counter = 0

        else:
            question_counter += 1

    return 'true'
```

I use regex at the top just to make it easier but you could just loop through the string without that and just have an if statement check if a character is a question mark. The regex leaves the string as just numbers and question marks, however, which I found a lot easier to work with.

Let me know if this works for you though, it gave the correct output with the 2 test cases you've given us so hopefully it works for any case.

Tested with:

```
print(QuestionMarks("arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"))
>> 'true'
print(QuestionMarks("9???1???9??1???9"))
>> 'false'
```